# Plotting dataframe with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

Let's say I have a dataframe named "df"

```
A <- seq(1, 10, 2)
B <- c("apple", "strawberry")

combination <- expand.grid(A, B) 
colnames(combination) <- c("A", "B")
 
df <- cbind(combination)
colnames(df) <- c("A", "B")
df$C <- seq(1, 10, 1)

df
```

What I want to do here is to draw one graph with 2 lines (each line represents "apple" and "strawberry" in column "B"), where x-axis is "A" and y-axis is "C", by using ggplot2. Can anyone help me out to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can enable in `aes()` the options `color` and `group` and set the `B` variable. Here the code using `ggplot2` functions:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
A <- seq(1, 10, 2)
B <- c("apple", "strawberry")

combination <- expand.grid(A, B) 
colnames(combination) <- c("A", "B")

df <- cbind(combination)
colnames(df) <- c("A", "B")
df$C <- seq(1, 10, 1)

df
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=A,y=C,color=B,group=B))+
  geom_line()
```

Output:

[image]